# What happens to lost coins in PoS?

Tags: proof-of-stake

Let's say a miner created an invalid block and the network catches the miner red handed. Then the miner loses all the coins staked on that block. What I do not understand is where do these coins go?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that they are burnt.

Comment: Can you add a reference to a particular implementation? I'd say it depends on the designer of the algorithm.

Comment: @Ismael agreed. It's what happens in Tezos for example. If someone catches it, it gets part of the bond and the rest is burnt. https://medium.com/@Tezzigator/tezos-baking-your-bonds-their-risks-78d90d47296

Comment: What do you mean by burning of coins? Where happens to the input scripts? and to whom are the output scripts assigned to?

Comment: Ethereum does not have input/output scripts, as it uses an account model rather than UTXO